# Error when inserting special characters such as Ñ and accents á, é, í, ó, ú. using BULK OPENROWSET from python

Tags: python, pandas, sql-server-2008, bulk, openrowset

I am having problems inserting information into a table in my SQLSERVER 2008 database from my python project using OPENROWSET BULK and even though the CSV file generates special characters such as Ñ, á, é, etc... When inserting it into the database these characters are corrupted.

This is where I create my CSV file:

`dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

I run a shutil copy to move that file to a specific path

`shutil.copy(cvs_path, ruta_destinoCSV)`

and I run the OPENROWSET BULK:

```
              bulk_insert_query = f'''INSERT INTO sgCliente (IdCliente,NomCliente,ApeCliente,NumDocumento,IdTipoDoc,NomTipoDoc,CodTipoDoc,Tip_docu,Sexo,FactorRh,GrupSangre,EstadoCivil,FecNacimiento,eMail,TelMovil,PrimerNombre,SegundoNombre,PrimerApellido,IndCentroExcelencia,IndDatosPersonal,IndHabilitado,IdTercero,CodUES)
                    SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET(
                    BULK '{ ruta_destinoCSV }',
                    FORMATFILE='{ ruta_destinoXML }',
                    CODEPAGE = 'UTF-8-SIG',    
                    FIRSTROW = 2) as t
                '''
```

This is the content of my XML fiel that I use as a formatfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="101" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="101" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="1" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="2" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="254" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="8"/>
      <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="15" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="18" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="20" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="21" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="22" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';' MAX_LENGTH="50" />
      <FIELD ID="23" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="5" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
   </RECORD>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="IdCliente" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="NomCliente" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ApeCliente" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="NumDocumento" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="IdTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLTINYINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="NomTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="CodTipoDoc" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Tip_docu" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="Sexo" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="FactorRh" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="GrupSangre" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="EstadoCivil" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="FecNacimiento" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="eMail" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="TelMovil" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="PrimerNombre" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="SegundoNombre" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="18" NAME="PrimerApellido" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="IndCentroExcelencia" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="20" NAME="IndDatosPersonal" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="21" NAME="IndHabilitado" xsi:type="SQLBIT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="22" NAME="IdTercero" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="23" NAME="CodUES" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

[These are a few lines from my CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nearn.png)

[This is what it looks like in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeiYn.png)

Comment: Usas Python2 o Python3 ?

Comment: You do know that even *extended* support for SQL Server 2008 ended over *4 years ago*, right? YOu really need to get that upgrade plan you (read your business) finalised back in 2017 or earlier, implemented.

Comment: Also, typing in all capitals is considered as SHOUTing, and is quite rude; please don't shout at us.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, also, has little/no support for UTF8 internally. I really suggest saving your file in a different codepage, ANSI/UCS-2/UTF-16, which would likely make your life easier.

Comment: If you use python2 have to do "ñ".encode("utf-8")

Comment: i use python 3.8.6 and i know that sql server 2008 has not support anymore, but is what i have, sorry for the capitals and thank you @Thom A, i change the encoding to ANSI and it's work!!! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, thank you to @THOM A.

Sql server 2008 has no support for UTF-8 so i have to encoding in ANSI, so the solution is change this:

```
dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='UTF-8-SIG')
```

for this:

```
dfClientes.to_csv(cvs_path, index=False, sep=';', encoding='ANSI')
```

Comment: good to see you found an answer !!